# How to use angle brackets in URL on Github Flavored Markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to use angle brackets in URL on Github Flavor Markdown.

Markdown:

```
1. Fork it ( http://github.com/<my-github-username>/oooooaaaa/fork )
```

Expect:

```
<li>Fork it ( <a href="http://github.com/">http://github.com/&lt;my-github-username&gt;/oooooaaaa/fork</a> )</li>
```

Actual:

```
<li>Fork it ( <a href="http://github.com/">http://github.com/</a><my-github-username>/oooooaaaa/fork )</my-github-username></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the angle brackets `<` and `>` cannot easily be used (or escaped or [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)) in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/), one workaround would be to used **square brackets**:

```
http://github.com/[my-github-username]/oooooaaaa/fork
```

That does give the expected result:

```
a href="http://github.com/">http://github.com/[my-github-username]/oooooaaaa/fork</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I use this in bundler: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/37362ef4b29c0cdaa4690283bd94309dd8f890a2

Answer (score 2):

Using backslash inside a `()[]` construction seems to work. (Tested on GitHub now.) It does not work on SO though.. For example:

```
1. Fork it ( [http://github.com/\<my-github-username\>/oooooaaaa/fork](http://github.com/\<my-github-username\>/oooooaaaa/fork) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this example below works as expected.

`http://github.com/(my-github-username)/oooooaaaa/fork`