# Escape angle brackets using Pod::Markdown

Tags: perl, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have problem with getting the correct behavior from [`Pod::Markdown`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Markdown) when using brackets `<` and `>`. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Pod::Markdown;

my $str = "=head1 OPTIONS\n\n=over 4\n\n=item B<< --file=<filename> >>\n\nFile name \n\n=back\n";

my $parser = Pod::Markdown->new;
my $markdown;
$parser->output_string( \$markdown );
$parser->parse_string_document($str);

dd $markdown;
```

Gives output:

```
"# OPTIONS\n\n- **--file=<filename>**\n\n    File name \n"
```

Which gives

[image]

on GitHub. So the part `<filename>` inside the `**` tag is probably treated as a HTML tag and therefore not shown.
The desired output would be

```
"# OPTIONS\n\n- **--file=\<filename\>**\n\n    File name \n"
```

where the brackets `<` and `>` should be escaped with a backslash.

**Update**

Seems like the problem is not restricted to double star sequences. I updated the question according to this..

Comment: Most Markdown processors that I have used "escape" angle brackets by replacing them with the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, not by backslashing literal angle brackets. Does that work here?

Comment: @Chris In principle I should not modify the Pod text/document. Inserting `&lt;` in the Pod document directly would not produce correct Pod to text conversion. So it is better to leave the Pod as it is.. The problem seems to be the output from Pod::Markdown. But then I have to modify the source code of Pod::Markdown in order to insert `&lt;`, which is not desired (since this is going to be used by other users than me)

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, a workaround seems to be to insert a backslash in a postprocessing step. For example:

```
$parser->output_string( \$markdown );
$parser->parse_string_document($str);
fix_escape_chars(\$markdown);

sub fix_escape_chars {
    my ($str) = @_;

    $$str =~ s/(?<!\\)>/\\>/g;
    $$str =~ s/(?<!\\)</\\</g;
}
```

This seems to work well.. (It works even inside URLs contrary to what is claimed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610244/how-to-use-angle-brackets-in-url-on-github-flavored-markdown) )..

Answer (score 1):

[`Pod::Markdown`](https://metacpan.org/release/Pod-Markdown) 3.000 has been released and fixes this issue.
Not all markdown processors recognize backslash escaped `<` chars, so I followed the Markdown spec suggestion of escaping `&` and `<` as html entities (`&amp;` and `&lt;`).